# Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported

Tags: windows, boost

I'm testing boost 1.5.7 on visual studio 2013. when i type boostrap to build binaries i found following errors in boostrap.log

to do that i use VS2013 ARM Cross Tools Command Prompt . i type cd C:/boost_1_57_0 
and just type bootstrap and hit eneter to build boostrap.

```
###
### Using 'vc12' toolset.
###

C:\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src\engine>if exist bootstrap rd /S /Q bootstrap 

C:\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src\engine>md bootstrap 

C:\boost_1_57_0\boost_1_57_0\tools\build\src\engine>cl /nologo /RTC1 /Zi /MTd /Fobootstrap/ /Fdbootstrap/ -DNT -DYYDEBUG -wd4996 kernel32.lib advapi32.lib user32.lib /Febootstrap\jam0  command.c compile.c constants.c debug.c execcmd.c execnt.c filent.c frames.c function.c glob.c hash.c hdrmacro.c headers.c jam.c jambase.c jamgram.c lists.c make.c make1.c object.c option.c output.c parse.c pathnt.c pathsys.c regexp.c rules.c scan.c search.c subst.c timestamp.c variable.c modules.c strings.c filesys.c builtins.c md5.c class.c cwd.c w32_getreg.c native.c modules/set.c modules/path.c modules/regex.c modules/property-set.c modules/sequence.c modules/order.c 
command.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
compile.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
constants.c
debug.ca
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
execcmd.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
execnt.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
filent.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
frames.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
function.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
glob.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
hash.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
hdrmacro.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
headers.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
jam.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
jambase.c
jamgram.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
lists.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
make.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
make1.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
object.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
Generating Code...
Compiling...
option.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
output.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
parse.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
pathnt.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
pathsys.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
regexp.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
rules.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
scan.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
search.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
subst.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
timestamp.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
variable.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
modules.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
strings.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
filesys.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
builtins.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
md5.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
class.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
cwd.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
w32_getreg.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
Generating Code...
Compiling...
native.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
set.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
path.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
regex.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
property-set.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
sequence.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
order.c
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\INCLUDE\crtdefs.h(404) : fatal error C1189: #error :  Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
Generating Code...
```

Line number 411 in the header file

```
/* Verify ARM Desktop SDK available */
#if defined (_M_ARM)
#if _CRT_BUILD_DESKTOP_APP && !_ARM_WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP_SDK_AVAILABLE
  #error Compiling Desktop applications for the ARM platform is not supported.
#endif  /* _CRT_BUILD_DESKTOP_APP && !_ARM_WINAPI_PARTITION_DESKTOP_SDK_AVAILABLE */
#endif  /* defined (_M_ARM) */
```

To overcome this isuue

```
1. i have installed VS again with windows phone SDK and tools for maintaining store apps for windows 8.
2. i have run vsvars32.bat which is located in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools - in visual studio Developer Command Prompt for VS2013 i type
cd  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\Tools
vsvar32.bat and hit enter
3. i tesed another machine which gave me the same error
4.
```

but nothing works on me. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2014/07/18/using-boost-libraries-in-windows-store-and-phone-applications.aspx

Comment: @HansPassant i have tried that way but i got error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200iB | 933.00 KiB/s
ffatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
atal: early EOF
fatal: index-pack failed
Clone of 'https://github.com/boostorg/serialization.git' into submodule path 'libs/serialization' failed

and still have the same Error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can ARM desktop programs be built using visual studio 2012?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11151474/can-arm-desktop-programs-be-built-using-visual-studio-2012)

Answer (score -3):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/745580/arm-configuration-doesnt-work

you can try this...

using the "Developer Command Prompt for VS2013" tool

Comment: improve your answer,with some explanation about it